# Java: Printing out all the integers in args array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, args

How do I print out a set of integers from my `args` variable in Java?

I tried:

```
System.out.println("The numbers are " + args.length);
```

But all that does is print out the number of elements in the array.

I want it so that if there are 5 arguments passed: `1 2 3 4 5` the output should be:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look if you like

```
  System.out.println("The numbers are "+Arrays.toString(args));
```

If not, you'll have to loop over the array and format it yourself.

Comment: does `Arrays.toString` print with the intermediate ","'s ?

Comment: yes, but also with (possibly unwanted) brackets around the list

Answer (score 2):

> But all that does is print out the numbers in the array not the numbers separately.

This seems to be somewhat unclear.

`args.length` gives the length of the array rather than its elements.

Use a for loop:

```
System.out.println("The numbers are ");

for(int i=0; i < args.length; i++)
    System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
```

Comment: The compiler gives me an error of "i cannot be resolved to a variable" When i resolve it with "int b = 0;" it gives me a single integer, rather than the integers in args.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for(String arg: args)
    System.out.print(arg + " ");
```

Comment: @MByD Your deducing powers are powerful, mine point me to `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: Then why did you add `+ " "` ?

Comment: @MByD To print out a **space** between each arg.